# How to keep slice alive to be used by C++ and dispose it after?

Tags: rust

I'm on a situation that I need to pass a slice `s: &[u8]` to C++ for it to be used for a while, and then it should pass back to Rust for deletion.

I plan to pass the slice as a `*const u8` by calling `s.as_ptr()` (anyone knows a better way?). However, the C++ function does not consume the buffer immediately. It stores it on a queue.

How should I pass this to C++ and how to delete it in Rust after usage?

Comment: Note that you can't ever artificially extend the lifetime of a slice. This is no exception with FFI. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28820781/extend-lifetime-of-variable

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28758246/how-can-i-convert-a-vect-into-a-c-friendly-mut-t

Comment: I believe that the only way to do so is by making your FFI stateful. Move the structure that your slice comes from (say a `Vec<u8>`) into a map owned by your FFI object, then place the call, then once you have received a callback from C++ that you can perform the cleanup, have the FFI object perform this cleanup.

Comment: Have you considered simply copying the slice on the C++ side? Then you wouldn't have to worry about the interaction between Rust and C++ lifetimes, each side would manage things on its own.